# create mailing - unable to load recipient group - insufficient permission

Tags: permissions, mailing, mosaico

I am using Mosaico and have a problem with the selection of Recipients for Mailings.
When I try to select a recipient civicrm seems to be searching infinitely for recipient groups and my firefox browser throws an error message refering to a necessary Permission Required: "insufficient permission: require administer CiviCRM"

But why should I require administration Permissions to create an mailing?
That does not seem to make sense. User has all permissions related to mailings, but of course no admin-permission.

Does anyone have an idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The code is trying to fetch the value of the setting hence it requires administrative permission. Theoretically it should allow minimum permission user to create mailings, looks like a bug.